# Определение онлайн-статуса скайпа

Tags: html, skype, javascript

Добрый день!
У кого-нибудь сохранился рабочий код для определения онлайн-статуса скайпа?
А то [на новом сайте генератор](https://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/generator) создает только синие/белые иконки, которые в данном качестве неюзабельны.
[Старая ссылка](http://www.skype.com/share/buttons/wizard/) не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Например:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/js/skypeCheck.js"></script>
</a>  <a href="http://www.skypeclub.ru/" target=_blank>Skype</a>: 
<a href="skype:НИК_В_СКАЙПЕ?chat"><img src="http://mystatus.skype.com/ТИП_КНОПКИ/НИК_В_СКАЙПЕ" style="border: none;" width="16" height="16" alt="My status" />
```

тип кнопки:

- mediumicon
- balloon
- bigclassic
- smallclassic
- smallicon

Проблема в том, что этот сервис грузит картинку секунд 15-20.

Comment: Что-то этот сервис лажу показывает, что скайп все время не в сети(((

Comment: Чтобы сервис не показывал всё время, что пользователь не в сети, нужно в настройках скайпа поставить галку что-то типа "Передавать статус в сеть".

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант.

1. Создать левый акк, добавить туда нужный акк (или сколько надо).
2. Создать приложение skypekit app
3. Монитором запускать это приложение
4. профит.

ЗЫ Вольный перевод [отсюда](http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Developer-Corner/Get-Skype-Online-Status-via-web-in-JavaScript-without-Skype/td-p/10526), последнее сообщение.
ЗЗЫ Гланды через... канеш.